# Is it halal to make ad revenue from sexy wallpapers?

Tags: halal-haram, business

I am making an application in which i am using sexy wallpapers but not full nude wallpapers. I am adding it to the Google Play store, where users can download it for free.

I earn money from an ad network which is integrated into the application. Once a user downloads the application and uses it, they will see the advertisements which are provided by the ad network.

That ad network company will then give me money for integrating their ad code to my application.

Would this income be *halal* or *haram*?

Answer (score 5):

Islam prohibits and stops its followers from showing any nude thing or anything that Islam considers as having low moral values. Islam is a religion that stops one from being nude, showing nude, advertising nude content by which Imaan of other people would be at a sake.

Earning via such content is itself prohibited.

Let me tell you an easy example of what is Halaal income, Halaal income as Holy Prophet described is any income that has some of hardwork included and which has no harmful effect on any other Muslim. The app would likely be qualified as a threat to people's Imaan.

Showing ads itself is acceptable, but the content has to be halal to display in public, e.g. wallpapers of nature or animals would be permissible.

Comment: is it haram or makruh ?

Comment: If I should say, it is both of them! Haram in a sense that it is not allowed and makruh as its a bad thing. You're showing them a content that they don't need to see and is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

According to one hadith of the prophet, the Jews were cursed because while they were forbidden from eating fat, they chose to sell the fat and eat from the profits instead.

Similarly to that would be any case where you're making money from something that you know is forbidden to you, but profiting from it on the grounds that others are willing to pay for it either because it is not forbidden to them or because they are unaware.

Ergo, the halality of any venture would be directly based on the halality of the product itself.  So the fundamental question is, how can "sexy wallpapers" be halal when the Qur'an explicitly commands believing women to dress modestly, and for believing men to lower their gaze?